# com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][10120][10898][4.19.49] Invalid operation: result set is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null

Tags: java, struts2, db2

In our Struts2 application For Fetching data we got **result set is closed**. we are using one structure for fetching resulset data. We are using **BaseResultSetHandler** fetch resulset data in DAO file.I am not able to find cause why resultset is closed. In the below i have mention code kindly help us

we are having BaseResultSetHandler abstract class

```
public abstract class BaseResultSetHandler {
    protected ResultSet resultSet;
    public abstract Object handleResult() throws SQLException;

    public Object handleResultSet(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException{
        setResultSet(rs);
        Object obj = handleResult();
        return obj;
    }
    public void setResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) {
        this.resultSet = resultSet;
    }
    public ResultSet getResultSet() {
        return resultSet;
    }
    public Integer getInteger(String columnName,ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException{
        return StringUtility.getInt(resultSet.getInt(columnName));
    }
    public String getString(String columnName,ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException{
        return StringUtility.getString(resultSet.getString(columnName));
    }
    public String getString(String columnName) throws SQLException{
        return StringUtility.getString(resultSet.getString(columnName));
    }
  }
```

We have one DatabaseManger class For handling database operation in that we have function for fetch data from database

```
  protected Object executePreparedQuery(String query, List arguments, BaseResultSetHandler BaseResultSetHandler, Connection useThisConnection)
        throws SQLException, InstantiationException, Exception, Throwable
      {
            ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {
          if (ReferenceCheckUtlity.isNull(useThisConnection)) {
              this.connection = getConnection();
          }else{
              this.connection = useThisConnection;
          }
          this.preparedStatement = this.connection.prepareStatement(query);

          if (arguments != null) {
                Iterator argumentsIterator = arguments.iterator();
                int index = 1;
                while (argumentsIterator.hasNext()) {
                     this.preparedStatement.setObject(index++, argumentsIterator.next());
            }
          }
          resultSet = this.preparedStatement.executeQuery();
          Object localObject2 =   BaseResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(resultSet);

        } finally {
            if(resultSet!=null){
                resultSet.close();
            }
            if(this.statement!=null){
                 this.statement.close();
            }
            if(this.preparedStatement!=null){
                 this.preparedStatement.close();
            }
            if(this.connection!=null){
                this.connection.close();
            }
        }
        return localObject2;
      }
```

In DAO File i have share only 2 method here there are lot of method in file approximate 25+ classes using **BaseResultSetHandler**

```
 public String getCheckId(String Id) throws NumberFormatException, SQLException, InstantiationException, Exception, Throwable  {
    ArrayList<Object> argumentList=new ArrayList<Object>();
    argumentList.add(Id);
    int cnt=Integer.parseInt(""+executePreparedQuery(getCheckIdSql(), argumentList, new getCheckIdHandler(), null));
    if(cnt==0){
        return "N";
    }else{
        return "Y";
    }
}
       private String getCheckIdSql() {
    StringBuffer query=new StringBuffer();
    query.append("select count(1) as cnt from EMPLOYEES where ID=? for read only ");
    return query.toString();
}

class getCheckIdHandler extends BaseResultSetHandler {
    @Override
    public Object handleResult() throws SQLException {
        int cnt=0;
        while(resultSet.next()){
            cnt=getInteger("cnt");
        }
        return cnt;
    }
}   
public HashMap<String,String> getMajorData() throws InstantiationException, SQLException, Exception, Throwable{
    LinkedHashMap<String,String> list = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
    list=(LinkedHashMap<String, String>) executePreparedQuery(getMajorDataSql(), null, new getMajorDataHandler(), null);
    return list;

}
private String getMajorDataSql() {
    StringBuffer query=new StringBuffer();
    query.append("select RMH_ode,MH_Name from RECMH order by MH_NM for read only");
    return query.toString();
}
class getMajorDataHandler extends BaseResultSetHandler {
    @Override
    public Object handleResult() throws SQLException {
        LinkedHashMap<String,String> list = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        while(resultSet.next()){
            String RMH_CD=resultSet.getString("RMH_CD");
            String MH_NM=resultSet.getString("MH_Name");
            list.put(RMH_CD+"*"+MH_Name, RMH_CD+"-"+MH_Name);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

And I have to also know it is sharing **BaseResultSetHandler**  resultSet Object

Comment: This is a FAQ.  Try the advice at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21461670

Comment: @mao Actually, it doesn't work as described at the link you provided. Even I set explicitly '...;queryCloseImplicit=1;allowNextOnExhaustedResultSet=2;' in a connection string (which are the default values for LUW connection), the code like 'while (resultSet.next()) {...}' works without any exception. Setting 'allowNextOnExhaustedResultSet=1' (allow next on exhausted RS) helps for code like  'while (resultSet.next()) {...}; resultSet.next();'. The next call after the while loop doesn't throw an exception upon such a setting, but it's some programming bug I believe...

Comment: Such an error can be seen if you have a setting to close the result set on commit (at the connection or statement level), autocommit turned on, and try to issue some other statements when you got a result set, but have not fetched all rows from it. If you have autocommit turned on, driver issues implicit commit after each such another statement, but not after each fetch for the result set.